# SugarCRM 6.5 CE: how to remove button in detailview according to a condition

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to remove buttons in detail view of a Lead if it is alredy converted.

I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213869/remove-button-in-detailview-with-condition-in-sugarcrm) and it use javascript to hide buttons. I'm trying to obtain same result via php.

This is my `view.detail.php` in `custom\modules\Leads\views\` folder

```
class LeadsViewDetail extends ViewDetail {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function preDisplay() {
        parent::preDisplay();

        if($this->bean->converted==1) {
            echo "hide";
            foreach ($this->dv->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'] as $key => $value) {
                unset($this->dv->defs['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][$key]);
            }
        } else {
            echo "show";
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code, after a Quick Repair & Rebuilt, I see "hide" or "show" correctly according to the Lead status but buttons are not updated correctly.

If I open a converted Lead after QR&R, I will never see the buttons.

If I open a unconverted Lead after QR&R, I will see the buttons all times.

I'm stuck with this situation. Can anyone explain me where is the problem? How I can solve it?
Every help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably handle this without extending the ViewDetail by using Smarty logic ("customCode") in `custom/modules/Leads/metadata/detailviewdefs.php`. It looks like the **Convert** button is already only rendered when the user has Edit privileges, so it's not a big deal to add one more condition to it...

```
$viewdefs['Leads']['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form]['buttons'][] = array('customCode' => '
{if $bean->aclAccess("edit") && $bean->converted}
<input title="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD_TITLE}"
  accessKey="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD_BUTTON_KEY}"
  type="button"
  class="button" 
  name="convert"
  value="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD}"
  onClick="document.location=\'index.php?module=Leads&action=ConvertLead&record={$fields.id.value}\'" />
{/if}');
```

Alternatively, if you do have several conditions and they'd get too messy or difficult for Smarty logic to be reasonable, we can combine a small amount of Smarty Logic with the extended ViewDetail.

This except of `custom/modules/Leads/metadata/detailviewdefs.php` is actually the out-of-the-box file from SugarCRM CE 6.5.24, where it looks like they've actually tried to make this customization easier by supplying a Smarty var `$DISABLE_CONVERT_ACTION`. For reference, it simply needs the global config variable `disable_convert_lead` to be set and enabled, but I suspect that this was a relatively new feature not included in earlier versions. Still, it's a good example of using the View to set a simple Smarty variable that we can pivot on:

```
<?php
$viewdefs['Leads']['DetailView'] = array (
  'templateMeta' => array (
    'form' => array (
      'buttons' => array (
        'EDIT',
        'DUPLICATE',
        'DELETE',
        array (
          'customCode' => '{if $bean->aclAccess("edit") && !$DISABLE_CONVERT_ACTION}<input title="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD_TITLE}" accessKey="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD_BUTTON_KEY}" type="button" class="button" onClick="document.location=\'index.php?module=Leads&action=ConvertLead&record={$fields.id.value}\'" name="convert" value="{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD}">{/if}',
          //Bug#51778: The custom code will be replaced with sugar_html. customCode will be deplicated.
          'sugar_html' => array(
            'type' => 'button',
            'value' => '{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD}',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
              'title' => '{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD_TITLE}',
              'accessKey' => '{$MOD.LBL_CONVERTLEAD_BUTTON_KEY}',
              'class' => 'button',
              'onClick' => 'document.location=\'index.php?module=Leads&action=ConvertLead&record={$fields.id.value}\'',
              'name' => 'convert',
              'id' => 'convert_lead_button',
            ),
            'template' => '{if $bean->aclAccess("edit") && !$DISABLE_CONVERT_ACTION}[CONTENT]{/if}',
          ),
        ),
```

We can combine this `$DISABLE_CONVERT_ACTION` reference with a `custom/modules/Leads/views/view.detail.php` like the following to set it based on whatever condition we want:

```
<?php
require_once('modules/Leads/views/view.detail.php');
class CustomLeadsViewDetail extends LeadsViewDetail {

  /*
   * while we might normally like to call parent::display() in this method to 
   * best emulate what the parnts will do, we instead here copy-and-paste the
   * parent methods' content because LeadsViewDetail::display() will set the
   * DISABLE_CONVERT_ACTION Smarty var differently than we want. 
   */
  public function display(){
    global $sugar_config;

    // Example One: Disable Conversion when status is Converted
    $disableConvert = ($this->bean->status == 'Converted');

    // Example Two: Disable Conversion when there is at lead one related Call
    // where the status is Held
    $disableConvert = FALSE;
    $this->bean->load_relationships('calls');
    foreach($this->bean->calls->getBeans() as $call){
      if($call->status == 'Held'){
        $disableConvert = TRUE;
        break; // exit foreach()
      }
    }

    // Example Three: Disable Conversion if the User is in a specific Role, e.g.
    // Interns who are great for data entry in Leads but shouldn't be making 
    // actual sales
    global $current_user;
    $disableConvert = $current_user->check_role_membership('No Lead Conversions');

    // In any of the above examples, once we have $disableConvert set up
    // as we want, let the Smarty template know.
    $this->ss->assign("DISABLE_CONVERT_ACTION", $disableConvert);

    // copied from ViewDetail::display();
    if(empty($this->bean->id)) {
      sugar_die($GLOBALS['app_strings']['ERROR_NO_RECORD']);
    }
    $this->dv->process();
    echo $this->dv->display();
  }
}
```

Comment: This may be ok. But what if the condition requires to evaluate, for example, fields of related beans?

Comment: Well, with more conditions it would get messier, and in that case I think you're correct and I would extend the `ViewDetail`. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: I think is also a good idea. It's plausible to use a Smarty variable assigned from the view.

Comment: Edited to reference the strategy (actually used in out of the box Sugar) with a few examples of Lead condition, related Call conditions, and current user role condition.